# Is it possible to add one mixin to every view in file automatically?

Tags: django, django-views

As in title. Is there a way to add, f.e. UserPassesTestMixin to every view in file without inheriting it in every one of them?

Let's say it would look like this:

```
Mixin: UserPassesTestMixin
Test:
    def test_func(self):
        # Some condition

# .../views.py

class FirstSampleView(SomeView):
    # View code


class SecondSampleView(SomeView):
    # View code
```

My target is that FirstSampleView, SecondSampleView and every other view in this file would have automatically my desired Mixin with according test_func.

Comment: I would advise against doing that. It makes the mixin *implicit*, and as the *Zen of Python* says: "explicit is better than implicit": it will make debugging harder in the future if you can not easily determine what the parent views are. You can however create a custom mixin yourself where you implement the `test_func`, and inherit it from there, so inherit `MyMixin`, not the `UserPassesTestMixin`.

Comment: That custom mixin is interesting idea. It's just that I need every view to have exactly same mixins as other views in file so I thought that It may be useful to just type it once and not repeat myself

Comment: but here we do *not* repeat the `test_func`, only the parent classes, this is often better than do that implicit, since people can not handle implicit data effectively.

Comment: I see you're more experienced than me so I'll go with your way, yet I think it would be useful to write just one line for whole file

Comment: perhaps it is worth looking how Django itself implements views (https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/views/generic/edit.py): it does that by defining mixins in the top of the file, and then most other views are not much more than "stacking" mixins together with the basic `View` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise that you make a *mixin* where you implement the `test_func`, so that looks like:

```
# app_name/views.py

class MyUserPassesMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    
    def test_func(self):
        return True  # do more sophisticated tests
```

Then you can mix this mixin into your views so:

```
class FirstSampleView(MyUserPassesMixin, SomeView):
    # View code, no test_func

class SecondSampleView(MyUserPassesMixin, SomeView):
    # View code, no test_func
```

This makes it explicit that you are using a mixin, but you do not repeat yourself with the `test_func` logic. This is implemented once in the mixin, and reused in all other views that make use of this mixin.

Comment: Also I want to ask, is it good idea to create folder called, f.e. customs in django project and create views.py for custom views and mixins.py for custom mixins to have easy access to them from every file in project?

Comment: @VIPE: Django itself does not seem to do that, or at least not if the mixins will only be used for views in one file. If it spans multiple `views.py`, it might be better to define a `mixins.py` file, and then import the mixins with `from app_name.mixins` import MyMixin`.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to create your custom class that include the mixin you need.

```
class BaseCustomView(SomeView, YourMixin):
   ...


class FirstSampleView(BaseCustomView):
   ...


class SecondSampleView(BaseCustomView):
   ...
```

Comment: I've also thought of this and it may be useful for my case